# Highcharts: markers not displayed

Tags: javascript, highcharts

check this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/dyackvbe/4/

The zoomable charts displays 1097 points.

If you look at the data points you will notice that some points should display a triangle marker.

```
{
"y": 20.6493939867,
"marker": {
    "enabled": true,
    "symbol": "triangle",
    "fillColor": "#578e6e",
    "radius": 5
}
 }
```

If you start zooming the chart, for exemple from may 14 to jan 15 the markers are displayed.

If you click on the reset button, the markers are displayed...

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

PS: this issue appeared once I upgraded highcharts. If I'm using an image instead a built in symbol it works: http://jsfiddle.net/9z0mp7jf/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have more than 1000 points in your serie.

Highcharts by default **doesn't check every single data-point for series with more than 1000 points**, it just checks the first one and then assumes that every other point is in the same format.

You need to tell highcharts to check every single point by changing the `turboThreshold` option to a higher number or to 0 to disable this feature. By setting `turboThreshold: 0,` your chart is correctly displayed.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63qkLmh5/)

[Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.turboThreshold)

Comment: Perfetto, grazie Luca